# React native DrawerLayoutAndroid and Switch component doesnt work well

Tags: react-native

I have a switch component on DrawerLayoutAndroid component. When I drag the switch component, drawer component is being slided.

How do I ensure when i drag switch, drawer panel is in blocked mode.

[EDIT]
Attaching the mocks below
[Mocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DX1w5.png)

Comment: Please share screenshots and code If possible at https://rnplay.org/

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a tap  on the Switch will toggle the switch state. If you want to make it drag as well and not let the other view become the responder, you can do that by implementing [GestureResponseHandler](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.27/docs/gesture-responder-system.html). Something like this.

```
const RespondHandler = {
 onStartShouldSetResponder: function (e) {
    return true;
 },
 onResponderGrant: function (e) {
    return true;
 }
};

<Switch {...RespondHandler}/>
```